# Batch - open a file where the filename contains a certain word

Tags: batch-file

So I have a batch file that checks for files in a directory against 4 different file extensions and processes them if they have the correct file extension:

```
set count=0
for %%x in (*.J_E, *.J_T, *.J_I, *.BCC) do (
  set /a count=count+1
  set choice[!count!]=%%x
)
for /l %%x in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo %%x. !choice[%%x]!
   tlv2txt !choice[%%x]! > !choice[%%x]!.txt
)
```

What I would like to do is add the ability to also use files where the filename contains a certain string like 'marmite'.
For example..

By running the batch file I would be looking to 'process' the files marked with an asterisk only:

- stuff.j_e *
- Things.j_t*
- MoreStuff.j_i *
- SomeThings.txt
- SomeMarmiteInA.jar *
- NotThisFile.jim
- OrThisOne.txt
- ThisOneThough.bcc*
- marmiteOnToast.tlv*

Like I said, I can get the file extensions, but I haven't the foggiest idea how to get filenames that contain..
Is this do-able?

Comment: Well, I seem to have answered my own question.
I'll leave the answer here for anyone else who might be experiencing the same problem..

The answer is 

`*marmite*.*`

So, using the example above;

 `for %%x in (*.J_E, *.J_T, *.J_I, *.BCC, *marmite*.*)`

Hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: You could post this as an answer and then even accept it, so tge question does no longer appear open...

Comment: Thanks aschipfl - done now.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I seem to have answered my own question!

I'll leave the answer here for anyone else who might be experiencing the same problem..

The answer is

```
*marmite*.*
```

So, using the example above;

```
for %%x in (*.J_E, *.J_T, *.J_I, *.BCC, *marmite*.*)
```

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it.

```
dir /a:-D /b | findstr /i "word"
```

**dir /a:-D /b** : This command will list all files in the directory.

**findstr /i**    : This command will check for the matching word in all files and lists them

**/i :** case insensitive search.
In our example, we will get a list of filename which have name containing string "word".

Please take this idea and proceed.

Comment: Thanks prudviraj, while useful - it's not quite what I'm after.
If I understand this correctly, this will find a string of text INSIDE files, what I was looking for was a _FILENAME_ that contains the string 'marmite' (eg: somemarmite.txt). I have since worked it out and posted the answer that works for me. Thanks for taking the time out anyway!

Comment: @Doug this command will get input from dir command and finds the string in the file name. verified from my end.revert if you thinks it is acting different.